# Connection refused while connecting to upstream, for Kubernetes .Net Core Service

Tags: kubernetes, .net-core, nginx-ingress

I have deployed an Angular UI and a .Net Core service to my Kubernetes cluster. I have exposed both the services using an NGINX ingress controller. However, when I hit my .Net service, I am getting the below error in the NGINX logs:

```
connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, 
client: 10.240.0.6, server: _, 
request: "GET /api/login/login HTTP/1.1", 
upstream: "http://10.244.0.54:85/api/login/login", 
host: "host_IP"
```

My microservice deployment YAML is

```
    ---
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
     name: login-microservice
     namespace: application
   spec:
     type: ClusterIP
     ports:
      - port: 85
     selector:
       app: login-microservice
      ---
     apiVersion: apps/v1
     kind: Deployment
     metadata:
     name: login-microservice
     namespace: application
     spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
     matchLabels:
     app: login-microservice
     template:
     metadata:
     labels:
       app: login-microservice
     spec:
       containers:
        - name: login-microservice
          image: XXX/login-microservice:latest
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
    - containerPort: 85
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: example-secret
  restartPolicy: Always
    ---
```

My Ingress for this service is :

```
  apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
  kind: Ingress
  metadata:
    name: ingress-login
      namespace: application
   annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS, HTTP, HTTPS"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "host_IP"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-credentials: "true"

    spec:
      rules:
       - http:
          paths:
           - path: /api
            backend:
             serviceName: login-microservice
             servicePort: 85
```

The cluster IP of the service is defined as 10.0.57.60

and the endpoint of the service is defined as 10.244.0.54.

Please help.

Comment: `http://10.244.0.54:85/api/login/login` this url has login repeated..is that intentional? Are you able access it via service IP or pod IP?

Comment: yes the "/login/login" is intentional. I am not able to access the service via the pod IP or cluster IP from the internet.

Comment: Can you access the service withour the ingress, using port-forward for example? Try the command `kubectl port-forward svc/login-microservice -n application 8080:85`. Them try to access `http://localhost:8080`. Let me know if the service is working.